# Ring to field homomorphism

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

(This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra Chapter 18 exercise I2.)

> Let $A$ be a ring.  Prove that if $f: A\rightarrow B$ is a homomorphism from $A$ *onto* $B$, and $B$ is a *field*, then the kernel of $f$ is a maximal ideal.

Proof attempt:

Let $K$ be the kernel of $f$. By the fundamental homomorphism theorem, $A/K\cong B$, so $B$ being a field implies $A/K$ is a field.  A field $F$ can have no ideals except $\{0\}$ and $F$. Therefore the kernel of $f$, $K$ in $A/K$, is a maximal ideal.

Does this look right?

Comment: yes; alternatively, for a commutative ring with $1$, $K$ is a maximal ideal if and only if $A/K$ is a field.